# Selecting HTML objects with Python and Bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm currently training code with python and bs4 and am testing to select objects from this site: http://www.metal-archives.com/lists/

I want to get the table containing the columns Band, Country, Genre and Status with the code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://www.metal-archives.com/lists/A')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

print([a.text for a in soup.select('td.sorting_1 a')])
```

But nothing happens, none information is shown.

I already tried in many different ways, like 'soup.find_all' e etc. When I inspect the web site with Chrome the table 'bandListAlpha' is there, but when I parse with Bs4, nothing happens.

I'm thinking it should be something with the 'request' method that is not bringing the full page, but I need some advice on how to obtain this information, what do I need to study? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

There is a metal-archives AJAX API that is used by the browser to get the desired data on the page. There are different ways to approach the problem, like, fire up a real browser via [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), or imitating these additional AJAX requests yourself in the code.

But you can also reuse something that's already there on github - there is a "metal archives" Python API wrapper called [`metallum`](https://github.com/lcharlick/python-metallum), you can install it directly from github:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/lcharlick/python-metallum
```

Here is an example code using this library:

```
In [2]: from metallum import band_search

In [3]: s = band_search('metallica')

In [4]: b = s[0].get()

In [5]: print(b.name, b.country, b.status, b.genres)
('Metallica', 'United States', 'Active', ['Thrash Metal (early)', 'Hard Rock/Heavy/Thrash Metal (later)'])
```

Comment: You done well. With your answer I learned the code itself, and furthermore,  the installation of python's API through github. At this time I working on variations of that metallum. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This page use JavaScript to fetch data, the real data is in this URL:

```
http://www.metal-archives.com/browse/ajax-letter/l/A/json/1?sEcho=1&iColumns=4&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=500&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=1&mDataProp_2=2&mDataProp_3=3&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=false&_=1482634713018
```

You can make request to this URL and get json data back.

Comment: Ow thank you! I spent time last weeks studying HTML structures and other stuff, because that's what  is missing for my evolution in this web scrapping.